# Domain Cannot be Found in Virtual XP Mode

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machines

I setup VirtualXP on a Windows 7 PC, but I cannot join it to our network/domain.  Keep getting the error that the Domain Cannot be Found.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you ping the domain controller from a command prompt in the virtual XP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a doubt it's your network settings. Change the network settings to use the actual physical network card and make sure that XPMode is configured to use your AD DNS server for DNS resolution.

Comment: Thanks Joe, changing the network card option under settings worked.

Comment: Glad to help...